# Adding pandas dataframe into sqlite table with unique constraint

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a fairly simple task that i fail. I currently refactoring my code. Until now i was iterating over all rows of the dataframe, cleaning the data and adding cleaned rows to the sqlite database.

Now i am cleaning the whole dataframe at once and need to add the data to the database. Instead of using cursor.execute on each iteration i was trying to use df.to_sql. However, i am getting an error:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(".temp_test_area.db")
df.to_sql('my_table', con=db, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

**IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: my_table.Time, my_table.String**

If if_exists is set to replace, it works. Now i noticed, if the database has some values already inserted (after running the code with if_exists='replace') the code with if_exists='append' also works, but not as intended. It adds more rows even if the unique condition is met.

The full code looks like this:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Int": [123, 34, 2, 123123],
        "Time": ["18:12:43", "01:12:43", "02:12:59", "01:12:43"],
        "Float": [72.12, 93.56, 84.1, 76.0],
        "String": ["foo", "foo", "bar", "foo"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
)

db = sqlite3.connect(".temp_test_area.db")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(
            ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            Int INTEGER,
            Time TIMESTAMP,
            Float REAL,
            String TEXT,
            unique (
                Time, String
            )
        )
    """
)

cursor.close()
db.close()

db = sqlite3.connect(".temp_test_area.db")
df.to_sql('my_table', con=db, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: you have TIME as a unique constraint and there are two rows with " "01:12:43""

Comment: Well. this is intentional to see if the unique condition at time and string actually works.

Comment: what is the question then?

Comment: The question(s) would be, how to use df.to_sql, when UNIQUE Constraint is set OR is it possible/impossible to use df.to_sql when UNIQUE Constraint is set. My "old code" is iteration over all df rows, insert them to the database and then committing. However, i don´t think my "old code" is anywhere near best practice.